# Is there such a thing as OpenCL-aware MPI - on Nvidia and AMD?

Tags: opencl, mpi

Do Nvidia GPUs support an OpenCL aware MPI, with similar functionality as its CUDA aware MPI?

Also, do AMD GPUs' OpenCL provide such functionality?

I would have thought a simple google search would have answered this, but surprisingly I did not find much info on this while there is a ton of info on  CUDA aware MPI!

Comment: Generic address spaces, upon which an OpenCL aware MPI would be built, are an OpenCL 2.0 feature. That immediately excludes a theoretical NVIDIA based OpenCL aware MPI because NVIDIA don't support OpenCL 2.0

Comment: I think OpenCL 2.0 support is limited to Intel graphics right now.

Comment: @talonmies Is there any information out there to gauge as to when one can expect GPU-aware MPI using OpenCL 2.0? (and thanks for the edits too!)

Comment: @Jeff From AMD's [website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/OpenCL2-Driver.aspx): "The AMD OpenCL 2.0 driver is compatible with AMD graphics products based on GCN first generation products or higher"

Comment: @crackjack Thanks.  Neither I nor anyone I know has AMD GPU hardware, so I don't track their support.  Good to know.